Confusion about local Minkowski frames
This is sort of a follow-up to the question I asked here: 
Confusion about timelike spatial coordinates
The important context is that we imagine a metric that, as $t\rightarrow\infty$, approaches the following:
$$ds^2=\text{d}t^2−\text{d}x^2$$
This is a metric in which the spatial coordinate $x$ is timelike, and it allows for closed timelike curves.
Mathematically, it is always possible to find a set of coordinates in which the metric locally looks like the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. What I don't understand is why this is physically acceptable in a situation like this.
From what I've learned in Sean M. Carroll's text, the transformation law for the metric at a point $p$ in spacetime is given by $(g_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu}})_p=(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\nu}}})_p(g_{\mu\nu})_p$. The Minkowski metric is given by $ds^2=-\text{d}t^2+\text{d}x^2$. If I've done my math correctly (I may have flipped the signs), the necessary derivatives at this point are
$$\frac{\partial t}{\partial \hat{t}}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{t}}=1$$
$$\frac{\partial t}{\partial \hat{x}}=-1$$
But then it would appear that (to first order) we have set $x=\hat{t}$ and $t=-\hat{x}$. In other words, to transfer to a local Minkowski frame, we need to reassign space and time. Why are we even allowed to do this? Does the Einstein Equivalence Principle require it for some reason?

Your statement "the spatial coordinate $x$ is timelike" is contradictory. At late times, $t$ is a spatial coordinate, and $x$ is the time coordinate. That's all that matters.

Ok. What is the formal justification that we must treat $x$ like the time coordinate here? Is the EEP all we need to justify this? Or is it just by definition?

Changing $x$ while keeping $t$ fixed gives a negative $ds^2$. That makes $x$ a timelike coordinate.

$x$ and $t$ are just symbols. We like to use the symbol $x$ to refer to the spatial coordinate and the symbol $t$ to refer to the time coordinate. Doing so helps communication with other people as you are giving the expected symbols the expected meanings.
However, there is nothing requiring that usage. You could make an obnoxious coordinate system where the symbol $x$ is used to refer to the time coordinate and the symbol $t$ is used to refer to the spatial coordinate. Likely you will confuse people by doing so, but there is nothing actually wrong with it.
That is all that is happening here. The result is simply telling you that you have put the symbols backwards from their usual usage in this part of your coordinate system. There is nothing related to the equivalence principle or anything similar. It is simply math.

Is it simply by definition of timelike vectors (that a vector is timelike if $g_{\mu\nu}V^{\mu}V^{\nu}<0$) that we can say $x$ and $t$ have switched roles? In other words, we assume this is possible because of how we defined the metric?

Yes. And physically we see that $x$ is measured by clocks, not rulers like usual.
